# Should I use state or call a function for better performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, redux

I have a Redux Form page with  some fields that have to be disabled when a condition is met.

My question is whether I should check this condition once when I do the `fetchData` call on mounting the component or if I should have some kind of function `isDisabled()` that will be called in the `render` (note: this function used the data fetched in the `didMount` that is already in the state).

I want to know which one (if any) would be more performant or is the *better* way to handle this in React.

I'll try to illustrate the two options.

**Option 1**: set in state on mount

```
componentDidMount() {
   fetch(...).then(result => {
      setState({ data: result.data, isDisabled: result.data.fixed === 1 }); 
   });
}

render() {
   const { isDisabled } = this.state;
   return (
      <Form>
        ...
        <Field disabled={isDisabled} />
      </Form>
   );
}
```

**Option 2**: check if it is disabled with a function, preventing using state twice for same data

```
componentDidMount() {
   fetch(...).then(result => {
      setState({ data: result.data }); 
   });
}

isDisabled() {
   const { data } = this.state;
   return data.fixed === 1;
}

render() {
   return (
      <Form>
        ...
        <Field disabled={this.isDisabled()} />
      </Form>
   );
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Render will run many times, sometimes multiple times a second. This means that you would be recalculating the field several times a second. This is fine for your example but with more complex use cases can become costly. Using setState() you will calculate only once. This is the more performant option.

Comment: With function components, you'd `useMemo` not state

Comment: @Bergi sadly we're using React 15.02 at my company (nothing I can't do about that) so I'm not able to use all the shiny new hooks for now 